# How do I regenerate the sitemap media item in a Headless SXA site without publishing?

Tags: sxa-jss, sitemap

I have an XM Cloud site I'm building locally and the current sitemap XML in the Media Library (`/sitecore/media library/Project/<project_name>/<project_name>/Sitemaps/<app_name>/sitemap`) is empty. How do I regenerate it with the pages I have added to my site for local testing?

A few things to note:

- We're on Sitecore 10.3 and JSS 21 (Sitecore License Details says `Sitecore XMCloud 1.5.62 (rev. 0)`).
- I cannot yet publish to Experience Edge, so if the generation requires publishing (as mentioned [in this article](https://www.balle-net.dk/posts/headless-sxa-sitemap/)), that won't work for me.
- I have tried deleting the file, but it was not automatically regenerating.
- When I hit the `/sitemap.xml` path on the CM, it generates and loads properly in the browser, but no media item is created.
- When I try to hit `/sitemap.xml` on the rendering host, it shows an empty document (the file from the media library).
- I have configured the `<site>/Settings/Site Grouping/<site_name>` item to have a target host name and host name and set the scheme to `https`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The solution

These are generated automatically when certain fields are saved on the site definition item (`/sitecore/content/<tenant>/<site>/Settings/Site Grouping/<site_definition>`). You can regenerate it by changing and saving (and then changing back/saving again) either of the below fields:

- Site name
- Start item

## For the curious

I discovered this by reviewing `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and searching for "sitemap." I found the below handler under the `item:saved` event:

```xml
<handler type="Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.SiteMetadata.EventHandlers.SitemapMediaHandler, Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.SiteMetadata" method="OnItemSaved" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.SiteMetadata.config"/>
```

Decompiling it, I found those two fields are inspected for changes and then a job is run to generate the media library item:

```
protected void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(sender, "sender");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    if (!JobsHelper.IsPublishing() && Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) is Item item && item.InheritsFrom(Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.Multisite.Templates.JSSSiteDefinition.ID) && Event.ExtractParameter(args, 1) is ItemChanges itemChanges && (itemChanges.FieldChanges.Contains(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Templates._BaseSiteDefinition.Fields.SiteName) || itemChanges.FieldChanges.Contains(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Templates._BaseSiteDefinition.Fields.StartItem)))
    {
        string change = itemChanges.FieldChanges[Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Templates._BaseSiteDefinition.Fields.SiteName]?.Value ?? item[Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Templates._BaseSiteDefinition.Fields.SiteName];
        SiteInfo siteInfo = SiteInfoResolver.Sites.FirstOrDefault((SiteInfo s) => s.Name.Equals(change.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (siteInfo != null)
        {
            JobManager.Start(new DefaultJobOptions("SitemapMediaHandler", "SXA", "scheduler", this, "InitSitemapMediaJob", new object[1] { siteInfo })
            {
                CustomData = item.Database
            });
        }
    }
}
```